# Is prophet Adam a descendant?

Tags: quran, tafseer

I have a doubt on verse on [3:34](https://legacy.quran.com/3/34).

> Descendants, some of them from others. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing.

Does it mean/say Adam was a descendant. Does this mean the Quran supports evolution?

Comment: You should have quoted the verse you are referring to. And @TheZ you should consider posting an answer!

Answer (score 1):

> "Indeed, Allah chose Adam and Noah and the family of Abraham and the family of 'Imran over the worlds - Descendants, some of them from others. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing." (3:34)

It doesn't say anywhere that Adam was a descendant but that some of the aforementioned groups were descendants of the others.